# Default expiry date of all types of file

Tags: g-wan, content-expiration

Despite of doing it in each file type handler, is there any simple way to set default expiry date of all types of file, e.g. json, jpg, html, css, js, etc?

Comment: A general purposes handler in gwan is named main.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nagi said, the `connection handler` called `/handlers/main.c` can be used to generate custom expiration HTTP headers.

You can also use `content-type handlers` which name in the `/handlers` directory must match the file type (`html.c`, `json.c`, `jpg.c`, etc.).

By default, G-WAN generates HTTP headers which may help proxy servers to do their job:

```
Date:           Thu, 29 Nov 2012 15:00:55 GMT
Last-Modified:  Sun, 25 Nov 2012 13:54:46 GMT
ETag:           "810c7fa9--50b22326-7ec3"
```

But a more fine-grained strategy can be used. That could be done in a future version by defining those content-related expirations in `content-type handlers`.

Proof that a server is a living (customer-driven) creature:

Comment: What if there are both main.c and html.c handlers in effect, but they have conflict http settings, e.g. in main.c expiry date is 10 days later, but in html.c is 1 year later?

Comment: What is the execution sequence of main.c and content type handlers? Or, if content type handler exists, would main.c be ignored?

Comment: **Connection handlers** are triggered at different CONNECTION states (ACCEPT, READ, WRITE, ERROR, etc.) while **Content-type handlers** are only triggered before sending a reply. Therefore, to answer your question, it depends on which CONNECTION state you are: **Connection handlers** are ALWAYS acting before **Content-type handlers** except for the BEFORE_WRITE state.